# SharePoint 2013 Permission Issue - (On Premises)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Recently i have added all user to SharePoint user group. After giving permission(Edit) to one of the group, even after giving individual permission(Edit) to document library neither any user can able to see the folder. When i check the particular user/group permission it shows the below details.

Limited Access Given directly

Edit, Limited Access Given through the "Administrative Staffs" group.

[image]

Both are same permission. But I found that in permission levels the Limited Access option is disabled and I cannot check in. Is that option making any conflict?

Can anybody sort out this.

Thanks

Comment: have you broken inheritance on library permissions? can you share screenshot of the permissions page of your document library?

Comment: Yes i broken inheritance first and then add users again to give group wise permission.

Comment: click on ellipsus (3 dots) besides folder name, then click on share and then advance settings. These will give you permissions of that specific folder. What do you see there?

Comment: User has been added with edit permission. Still user cannot login, its says "Sorry, you don't have access to this page "

Comment: please add screenshot of folder permissions and library permissions to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if permissions on the *SitePages* or *Pages* library are broken. Please give access to people on the *Site Pages* or *Pages* library as well.

Also, you need minimum view only or limited access permissions on the site which contains your document library.

Comment: SitePages permission was't broken and after i break it and add user again with 'Edit' and 'Read' permission for both site page and document library. When i did this process 'Limited Access' level has gone. But still user cannot able to login.

Shall i reset all permission and start from scrap ?? Can you guide me

Comment: You do not need to break permissions on pages/site pages. does the group have read permission on the site?

Comment: With group permission user cant able to login but when i give the permission individually to user (Both site and library) he can login and see the main page. But he can't see any folder/files inside document library. Some the folders he is able to enter but it showing "There are no items to show in this view of the "test" document library. To add a new item, click "New" or "Upload"."